# Laravel 5.6 Wherein with If condition

Tags: laravel

My function in ProductRepository.php is like this :

```
public function listProductsFilter($columns=[],$category=[])
    {
        $keywords = [];
       foreach($columns as $key => $value){
         $keywords[] = [$key, 'LIKE', '%'.$value.'%'];
        }

         $query=  $this->model
         ->join('category_product', 'products.id', '=', 'category_product.product_id')
          ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
         ->where('products.is_deleted', 0)
         ->Where($keywords)
         ->whereIn('category_product.category_id', $category)
         ->get();


         return $query;
    }
```

I add a condition to check whether category exist or not. I tried to like it, but there comes error :

```
if(isset($category))
         ->whereIn('category_product.category_id', $category)
```

syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

How can I solve the error?

Comment: Use:

if(isset($category))
    $this->whereIn('category_product.category_id', $category)

Comment: same error i got it syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Comment: @KamesP : please mark as accepted if works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    public function listProductsFilter($columns=[],$category=[])
        {
            $keywords = [];
           foreach($columns as $key => $value){
             $keywords[] = [$key, 'LIKE', '%'.$value.'%'];
            }

             $query=  $this->model
             ->join('category_product', 'products.id', '=', 'category_product.product_id')
              ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
             ->where('products.is_deleted', 0)
             ->Where($keywords);
if(isset($category))
              $query= $query->whereIn('category_product.category_id', $category);
             $query= $query->get();


             return $query;
        }
```